# What is $aria in Angularjs ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is $aria in Angularjs?. What is the purpose of this service? I am new in angularjs . I checked angularjs documentation but I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the action of module we have added in dependency. This is a service in module ngAria. It uses to improve accessibility.

Supported directives:

1. ngModel
2. ngDisabled
3. ngRequired
4. ngReadomly
5. ngChecked
6. ngValue
7. ngShow
8. ngHide
9. ngClick
10. ngDblClick
11. ngMessages

For more info refer

[Examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility)

[About aria provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria/provider/$ariaProvider)

[Video to understand about aria](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ng-aria-to-automatically-improve-your-angularjs-accessibility)

Answer (score 2):

angular.module('app', ['ngAria']);

The ngAria module provides support for common ARIA attributes that convey state or semantic information about the application for users of assistive technologies, such as screen readers.

`Example`[https://codepen.io/marcysutton/pen/azbdGa]

`This too`[https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ng-aria-to-automatically-improve-your-angularjs-accessibility]

`Check this:` [http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2014/11/using-ngaria.html#why-ngaria]